# Create dropdown filter options for a column when you create a .csv file from php

Tags: php

Does anybody know how to create drop down/ filter options for a particular column when you create a .csv file with php. I am generating a .csv template and want to give the option of choosing only the filter values as cell data for that column.

Answer (score 2):

CSV files are plain text files containing rows of data, each column separated by a comma (or other character).

The functionality you describe isn't part of CSV.

Creating a drop-down menu to filter a column would be a function of something viewing the data in the CSV, such as a spreadsheet program.  Take a look at [PEAR's Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer](http://pear.php.net/package/Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer), it might let you create a spreadsheet with a filter dropdown.

Comment: is it possible using php and html2pdf